# IPython Notebook: some Latex expressions are not displayed correctly in Firefox

Tags: firefox, latex, ipython, fedora

IPython Notebook view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvpxJ.png

HTML View in nbviewer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBgsO.png

Here you can see some math expressions displayed in nbviewer and in a running Notebook instance on my computer. The former works correctly (with MathJax, so MathJax works), and the latter does not. I'm using IPython 2.0.0, Firefox 32.0 on Fedora 20.

That problem is with me since last winter, so now I'm really tired and into solving it. So, can anyone help me with this question?

PS: 
In Chrome it works correctly both ways

Comment: May be it's a sign for me to switch from Firefox, which is sad, because Google then will be just everywhere =(

Comment: That's bizarre, because in both the running notebook and nbviewer, the equations are rendered by [Mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/), so they should be the same in both cases. It's possible that you have an older version of Mathjax installed on your computer.

Comment: Hey, thanks, man! I've solved it! After downloading MathJax 2.4 zip-archive, I used "python3 -m IPython.external.mathjax /path/to/source/MathJax...2.4.zip" on it, and now it all renders correctly! I think the problem was that I've done that action really long ago with, as you said, old version or something alike. Thanks again for the idea!

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got it fixed.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem and with firefox.   If I adjust the math renderer on the notebook equations then all the equations in the notebook stop displaying.  And there is no way to get them back.   Perhaps after reloading a few times?  The mathML addon with firefox makes it impossible to see equations in the notebook but seems to fix problems with equations on other websites.  I tried installing Mathjax inside ipython, no joy.   I am having  problems with MathJax in firefox in many different settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comment section for the answer, solved with manual updating the MatjJax local ipython installation.

Beautiful again!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM5I6.png

Answer (score 0):

Adding clarification, this explains the "why" behind the fix: [Firefox and local fonts - Installing and Testing Mathjax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/installation.html#firefox-and-local-fonts)

Towards the end of the discussion, it says: "One solution to this problem is to install the MathJax fonts **locally**, so that Firefox will not have to use web-based fonts in the first place." This is essentially what happened when you ran the MathJax 2.4 zip-archive script you mentioned in your reply comment.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, I suppose the problem rather concerned IPython Notebook itself, as long as MathJax worked everywhere else as expected.